# A problem about NIntegrate the smaller eigenvalue for a matrix

Tags: matrix, numerical-integration

Define a matrix and a function as

```
h[y_] := {{101, 2 (1 + E^(-I) + E^(-I* y) + E^(-I* (1 + y)))}, {2 (1 + E^I + E^(I *y) +E^(I* (1 + y))), 1}};

htest[y_] := N[Block[{e, f}, {e, f} = Eigensystem[h[y]]; {e, f} = {e[[#]], f[[#]]} &@Ordering[N[Re[e]]];Return[{Re[e], f}]]]
```

So, by `htest[y]`, we should get an ordered eigensystems for matrix `h[y]`. For instance, `h[1][[1]]` gives you `{0.621825, 101.378}`, but `h[x][[1]]/.x->1` gives you `{101.378, 0.621825}`, whose first element isn't the smaller one.

When I try to calculate some integrals, say the integral of the smaller eigenvalue:

```
NIntegrate[htest[x][[1]][[1]], {x, 0, 2}]
```

you will get `145.07`. It's not th result from smaller eigenvalue but from `h[y][[1]][[1]]/.y->x`. Actually, you can

```
Plot[htest[x][[1]][[1]], {x, 0, 2}]
Plot[htest[x][[1]][[1]] /. x -> y, {y, 0, 2}]
```

to see the difference.
So, my problem is how can I integrate the smaller eigenvalues by using `NIntegrate`?

Comment: When editing, use the little question mark icon for help - readability can make the difference between getting answers and not...

Comment: Perhaps define your integrand as `f[x_?NumericQ] := htest[x][[1]][[1]]`?  See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for your help. I think that's the right approach to solve this problem.